# Как правильно: "должен" или "должны"

Tags: грамотная-речь, единственное-множественное-число

Функциональные возможности коммутатора 3-го уровня **должны** обеспечивать стабильную и отказоустойчивую передачу

Comment: Если вам дан хороший ответ, отметьте его галочкой.

Answer (score 1):

Так как речь идет о возможностях (мн.число), то **возможности должны**:

> Функциональные возможности коммутатора 3-го уровня должны обеспечивать стабильную и отказоустойчивую передачу

Answer (score 1):

Чисто грамматически согласование по числу такое: "возможности должн**ы**". Однако по смыслу "стабильная и отказоустойчивая передача" *входит в число* возможностей устройства, не "обеспечивается" ими (*коммутатор* должен обеспечивать то-то и так-то; это *является* или *должно быть* одной из его функциональных возможностей).

Comment: Это достаточно часто используемые в инструкциях обороты. За 16 лет работы в телекоммуникационной компании я много таких повидал.

Comment: Возможно,  **технические** возможности коммутатора должны обеспечивать такие **функциальные** возможности как стабильная и отказоустойчивая передача